# Eigenvalues of submatrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am interested in results on the eigenvalues of submatrices.

Given a symmetric and positive-semidefinite matrix $M$, denote the submatrix obtained by deleting the ith column and jth row as $[M]_{ji}$.

How does the spectra $\lambda([M]_{ji})$ relate to the spectra $\lambda(M)$?

I know when looking at principal submatrices (ie, $i=j$), we get an interlacing property.  However, I can't seem to find such results for other submatrices.

Comment: First, note that your $[M]_{ji}$ is no longer symmetric. Next, note that for the identity matrix $I_n$, $[I_n]_{1n}$ is nilpotent. So I think relatively little can be said. 

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:
http://www.math.wm.edu/~ckli/ima/note-2.pdf